# Filtering in prisma based on a calculated field

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, prisma

I'm trying to implement a distance filter in my webapp. Backend technologies include prisma, apollo and graphql. The user's location (as an object containing latitude and longitude points) is sent to the backend, where it the distance to a particular location will be calculated and filtered using prisma's built in filtering relations. I have other filters (busyness, noisiness, price) that are being filtered correctly, and I want the same behavior for distance as well.

The prisma schema is as follows:

```
model Business {
  id              Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  stringId        String         @unique
  name            String
  street          String
  city            String
  province        Province
  postalCode      String
  busyness        filterOptions?
  noisiness       filterOptions?
  price           filterOptions?
  Location        Location?
}

model Location {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  latitude  Float     @unique
  longitude Float     @unique
  Business  Business  @relation(fields: [busId], references: [id])
  busId     Int       @unique
}
```

existing function to return all businesses:

```
async function returnAllBusinesses(parent, args, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.business.findMany({
    where: {
      name: { contains: args.filterByName, mode: "insensitive" },
      busyness: args.busyFilter,
      noisiness: args.noiseFilter,
      price: { in: args.priceFilter.length ? args.priceFilter : undefined },
    },
    orderBy: {
      id: "asc",
    },
  });
}
```

I couldn't query the database using `context.prisma.findMany()` initially to return all the databases, then perform the calculation to convert the 2 points latitudes and longitudes into a distance, then apply the filter again.

How can I play around with prisma, apollo and graphql to implement all my filters in one place?